# Android 10 image upload error: kotlin.io.NoSuchFileException: : The source file doesn't exist

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent

Hello i am trying to take image from local storage and upload it to the server. But on android 10 and stock android 9 its not working. Its giving me this error:

```
Fatal Exception: kotlin.io.NoSuchFileException: : The source file doesn't exist.
       at kotlin.io.FilesKt__UtilsKt.copyTo(Utils.kt:183)
       at kotlin.io.FilesKt__UtilsKt.copyTo$default(Utils.kt:181)
       at id.zelory.compressor.UtilKt.copyToCache(Util.kt:82)
       at id.zelory.compressor.Compressor$compress$3.invokeSuspend(Compressor.kt:25)
       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:738)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
```

Heres is my code to take image using intent:

```
   override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)



        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
            imageUri = data!!.getData()!!

            updateAdapter(imageUri)

        }


    }
```

and the crash i am getting is in here:

```
  fun uploadImagetoS3(presignedUrl: String, imageUri: Uri) {

        var file = File(getRealPathFromURI(activity!!, imageUri)) <- here its crashing


        MainScope().launch {

            file = Compressor.compress(activity!!, file)

            feedbackViewmodel.uploadImageToS3(
                presignedUrl,
                RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), file)
            )

        }


    }
```

Here is that method getRealPathFromURI :

```
  private fun getRealPathFromURI(context: Context, contentUri: Uri): String {
        var cursor: Cursor? = null
        return try {
            val proj = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)

            cursor = context.contentResolver.query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null)

            val column_index: Int = cursor!!.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)

            cursor!!.moveToFirst()

            cursor.getString(column_index)

        } catch (e: Exception) {


            ""
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close()
            }
        }
    }
```

WHat am i doing wrong? its working properly till android 9 in most of the devices, but in android 10 and stock android one it is crashing.

I have also already added
`android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`
in manifest. It was working properly in between last week.
But its still crashing again.

Heres my uploadimage to s3 method:

```
 fun uploadImageToS3(url: String, requestBody: InputStreamRequestBody) {
        showProgress(true)


        restClient.noAuthClient.create(ApiService::class.java)
            .uploadImage(url, requestBody)
            .enqueue(object : Callback<Void> {

                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<Void>, response: Response<Void>
                ) {
                    showProgress(false)

                    if (response.isSuccessful) {

                        uploadImageData.postValue(true)
                    } else {

                        errorData.postValue(response.message())

                        Log.e("xoxo","image upload error onresponse: "+response.toString())


                    }

                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<Void>, t: Throwable) {

                    showProgress(false)

                    errorData.postValue(t.message)

                    Log.e("xoxo","image upload error: "+t.toString())


                }
            })


    }
```

and here it is in the apiservice:

```
    @PUT
    fun uploadImage(@Url url: String, @Body image: InputStreamRequestBody): Call<Void>
```

The error from retrofit as logged in code onResponse:

```
2020-05-10 03:29:37.319 7903-7903/in.example.com E/xoxo: image upload error onresponse: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=501, message=Not Implemented, url=https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/example.com-prod-backend/events/11765_6e6e5680a5009e7bc1932e08?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIARBVMRBYEREFA7JZK%2F20200509%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200509T215929Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=7271b6c8c1b89d4b468abc20dd74f2a4f820dfd158781f905b9f09b580c15e02}
```

Also here is the okhttp logs in case you want:

```
2020-05-10 03:37:44.070 7903-8784/in.example.com D/OkHttp: --> PUT https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/example.com-prod-backend/events/11765_be7a06c969513557e2830176?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIARBVMRBYEREFA7JZK%2F20200509%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200509T220736Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=3dcaf93b15f0edf4224a4ce6c56bda2d9e9b2aa94144ba12e561f93b942e65a4
2020-05-10 03:37:44.071 7903-8784/in.example.com D/OkHttp: Content-Type: image/jpeg
2020-05-10 03:37:44.122 7903-8784/in.example.com D/OkHttp: --> END PUT (binary -1-byte body omitted)
2020-05-10 03:37:44.145 7903-8784/in.example.com W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
2020-05-10 03:37:44.149 7903-8784/in.example.com I/System.out: e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaHttp
2020-05-10 03:37:44.150 7903-8784/in.example.com D/Linux: [Posix_connect Debug]Process in.example.com :443 
2020-05-10 03:37:44.213 7903-8784/in.example.com D/OpenSSLLib: OpensslErr:Module:12(177:); file:external/boringssl/src/crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c ;Line:168;Function:ASN1_get_object
2020-05-10 03:37:44.217 7903-8784/in.example.com D/OpenSSLLib: OpensslErr:Module:12(177:); file:external/boringssl/src/crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c ;Line:168;Function:ASN1_get_object
2020-05-10 03:37:44.867 7903-8784/in.example.com D/OkHttp: <-- 501 Not Implemented https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/bexample.com-prod-backend/events/11765_be7a06c969513557e2830176?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIARBVMRBYEREFA7JZK%2F20200509%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200509T220736Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=3dcaf93b15f0edf4224a4ce6c56bda2d9e9b2aa94144ba12e561f93b942e65a4 (744ms)
2020-05-10 03:37:44.867 7903-8784/in.example.com D/OkHttp: x-amz-request-id: A665CB05729AEB19
2020-05-10 03:37:44.868 7903-8784/in.example.com D/OkHttp: x-amz-id-2: KN3aeeqGgblXcYs7wvF9J7IAdjKSagFHEAy9w4eVkN93IRtO6CoJY6rLGlpavK3Lzb5yl0uOH7o=
2020-05-10 03:37:44.868 7903-8784/in.example.com D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/xml
2020-05-10 03:37:44.868 7903-8784/in.example.com D/OkHttp: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
2020-05-10 03:37:44.868 7903-8784/in.example.com D/OkHttp: Date: Sat, 09 May 2020 22:07:36 GMT
```

Comment: Instead of using `RequestBody.create()`, use the `InputStreamRequestBody` from [this OkHttp issue comment](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3585#issuecomment-327319196). You provide the same media type as before, but instead of a `File` (that you are incorrectly creating), you provide a `ContentResolver` (from `getContentResolver()` on a `Context`) and the `Uri`.

Comment: @CommonsWare But the RequestBody thing comes post the crash code. Or do u mean to remove that getRealPathFromURI call also and do this directly ?

Comment: "Or do u mean to remove that getRealPathFromURI call" -- yes. Sorry, I should have been clearer.

Comment: @CommonsWare Hey so i did this:             feedbackViewmodel.uploadImageToS3(presignedUrl, InputStreamRequestBody(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), context!!.contentResolver,imageUri)) but that s3 link is giving error : Not implemented. While in old way Request.create i was able to upload, but not in android 10. Is there some step i am missing or is wrong?

Comment: I do not have enough details here to advise you. You might consider adding your `uploadImageToS3()` implementation and the full stack trace to the question.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have added uploadImageToS3() above. Can you please check and tell me what is wrong or what am i missing.

Comment: I also need the full stack trace where this "Not implemented" message is appearing. That will require you to fix your error logging: replace `Log.e("xoxo","image upload error: "+t.toString())` with `Log.e("xoxo","image upload error", t))`.

Comment: ok doing it immediately and posting. Please wait.

Comment: I have added it above, its not coming inside onfailure. Its coming in onResponse only. So i cannot have that t throwable variable. So i decided to print the entire response  and show as it is.

Comment: Sorry, that is coming from the S3 Web service. 501 Not Implemented usually means you are using the wrong HTTP method (i.e., `PUT` is not supported for that URL). However, it is possible that Amazon is using that for some other meaning here.

Comment: @CommonsWare but bro i was able to upload my images there before and also was able to see it later in a get api response also that images are getting uploaded.  I have added okttp logs as well above. Incase you need it. Its just that my method/my way of doing it was not working in android 10 and android one. And application kept crashing.

Comment: The `binary -1-byte body omitted` message suggests that the `InputStreamRequestBody` is not working. It is possible that whatever `restClient` is does not like the fact that `contentLength()` is returning `-1`, even though that is a documented return value. Your code from before is unreliable and will crash on lots of devices, as not every `Uri` has a `DATA` column, and even those that do might point to places where you do not have filesystem access.

Comment: yes but now i removed that 'getRealPathFromURI' call as you said. And making call directly to the uploadImageToS3 with the InputStreamRequestBody as you said.
So still is it trying to access data column ?  or do u mean this line 'imageUri=data!!.getData()!!' inside onActivityResult() is wrong?

Comment: All I can suggest is trying to figure out what is going wrong with `InputStreamRequestBody`. For example, you might try calling `contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)` yourself to confirm that you have permission to read the content from the `Uri`.

Comment: " or do u mean this line 'imageUri=data!!.getData()!!' inside onActivityResult() is wrong? " -- well the `!!` make me nervous, but otherwise that bit of code seems fine, assuming that you are using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, or `ACTION_PICK` for making the request in the first place.

Comment: Yes i am using ACTION_PICK :                  Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you find the fix for this issue ?